# Total reflection and optic fibre basic view on how the formulas work

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fiber-optics

I am a transfer student as such I am having problems with the homework because they are in french. The homework is about total reflection as well a fibre optics in here I have 2 formulas which I don't seem to understand when or for what they used for $$n_1 x \sin I_1=n_2 x \sin I_2$$ as well as $$I_l=\frac{n_2}{n_1}$$ I am totally confused because I see them both used at the same time. Can I please get a clear answer as to what is $n_1$, $n_2$, $I_1$, $I_2$ and $I_l=I_{\text{limit}}$.

Comment: Are you sure that those formulae you gave are correct? I edited your post for reasons of formatting primarily, but I cannot edit the formulae themselves as this would 'Clearly contradict with authors intent'. You can cancel the $x$'s from the first formula assuming $x\ne 0$, but I do believe it is Snell's law that you are making reference to here. The other formula needs some revision also.

Comment: I believe the "x" were multiplication signs and yes, the second equation seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first formula,
$$n_1\sin I_1 = n_2 \sin I_2$$
is Snell's law, or the law of refraction, which relates the angles of incidence and refraction ($I_1, I_2$) to the refractive indices of the two media ($n_1, n_2$).

[image]

I believe your second equation is meant to read:
$$\sin I_\mathrm{limit} = \frac{n_2}{n_1}$$

If so, $I_\mathrm{limit}$ would be the critical angle, the (minimum) angle of incidence at which you start getting total reflection, i.e. the angle of incidence at which the angle of refraction becomes 90°. This equation follows from Snell's law if you put the angle of refraction $I_2=90°$ and therefore $\sin I_2=1$. Of course this total reflection only works if $n_2/n_1 <1$, i.e. only when going from an optically dense (large $n$) to an optically less dense (smaller $n$) material.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the refractive indices.  $I_i$ and $I_2$ are the angles of incidence and refraction measured from the normal to the interface. At the critical angle the angle in the lower refractive index material is $90$ degrees and that in the higher refractive index material is $I_{\rm critical}$,  so $\sin I_{\rm critical}= n_{\rm lower}/n_{higher}$.